# Find Pareto front of a two-objective function of a two-dimensional variable of different dimmension.

Tags: optimization, matlab, game-theory, convolution, numerical-optimization

I need to find Pareto front of two objective functions $J_g(g,h)$ and $J_h(g,h)$ where $g$ is a matrix (image) and $h$ is a small convolution (blur) matrix
\begin{equation}
J_{g}(g, h)=\frac{1}{2}\|h * g-z\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}^{2}+\int_{\Omega} \alpha_1|D g| d x
\label{7}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
J_{h}(g, h)=\frac{1}{2}\|h * g-z\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}^{2}+\int_{\Omega}\alpha_2|D h| d x
\label{8}
\end{equation}
The problem is those two functions depend on each other and are of two different dimmension.
I faced the same problem while trying to minimize them simultaneously (i derived the two
and used a gradient method to solve the equations, in the first step i fix $h$, solve $\frac{\partial J_{g}}{\partial g}=0$, i obtain a value $g$ that i use when fixing $g$ in $\frac{\partial J_{g}}{\partial g}=0$ and repeat till convergence).
$z$ is a given blurred image.
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial J_{g}}{\partial g}=h(-x,-y) *(h * g-z)-\alpha_1 \nabla \cdot \frac{\nabla g}{|\nabla g|}=0 \quad x \in \Omega
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial J_{h}}{\partial h}=g(-x,-y) *(g * h-z)-\alpha_2 \nabla \cdot \frac{\nabla h}{|\nabla h|}=0 \quad x \in \Omega
\end{equation}
None of the predefined functions in Matlab (paretosearch,gamultiobj) worked for me.